Why isn't the main armature visible?
I'm completely new to rigging. I downloaded a model of an alien hand that I'd like to animate grabbing a plate. After watching a few beginner tutorials, I'm trying to set it all up. As you can see on the 'Data" tab for 'Bones', I've opted to show the bone shapes, colors, and 'in front'. The tutorials I watched indicated that by selecting 'in front' I should be able to see all bones in Pose view. But the largest bone/armature isn't showing up like the others.
You can see in the screenshots that it's visible in Solid view but not really accessible. And it doesn't show up in rendered view at all. What did I do wrong?



The bones of the main armature are displayed as an outline because you have 4 armatures, and only 3 of them (those for the fingers) are in Pose mode, the main armature is still in Object mode. You have selected it after switching modes (Object -> Pose). In the outliner,  Click on the white dot to the left of the name, the Mode toggling, to put the armature to Pose mode. You will then see 4 icons of the type "white dot + stick figure" in the first column of the outliner.

But... why don't you use just one armature that has all bones in a proper bone hierarchy?

I can't answer your question. I've watched what seems like extensive tutorials on YouTube... they're all about an hour long. But I don't recall hearing the phrase "bone hierarchy". The biggest challenges of learning 3D are not knowing if something is a good tutorial and not knowing the proper technical names of tools or steps to know what to look up. Thank you for your responses! I'll definitely try what you suggested and look up what you asked about in your question. Let me know if you have any suggestions of processes or search terms to use when looking up tutorials for rigging or posing.

Your suggestion worked. Thanks!

By bone hierarchy I mean that the finger bones are children of the palm bones, and the palm  & the thumb bones are children of the hand bone which is the root. If you have an arm then the hand is a child of the forearm, that is a child of the upper arm, and so on. Here is a Rigify hand. You can see there is only 1 armature that has all the 20 hand bones and you can see the hierarchy in the outliner (4). You can do the same if you select the 4 armatures and join them (Ctrl+J). 1 armature is enough & you can easily create poses for it.

Oh I see! I guess I didn't create a proper bone hierarchy as you describe it because the beginner tutorials I've watched feature very simple hands that are more like mittens. They only created a thumb bone and one main hand bone. It didn't occur to me to create something more complicated. I did just try to to join them per your suggestion and the armature became huge. But I'm sure I can shrink it down. Thanks again for your help!
